# Почему не рекомендуют ставить ключевое слово inline в реализации метода?

Tags: c++, inline

Мой коллега увидел, что я ставлю inline методам get и set и в объявлении метода и в реализации и сказал, что так делать не стоит, но аргументировать это не смог. Я тоже когда-то про такое слышал, но информации найти не смог. Я знаю, что компиляторы сейчас забивают даже на форсинлайны и обычный inline им вообще не указ. Но всё-таки, правда ли что inline ставить лучше только в объявлении метода и какие у этого есть объективные причины?

Comment: Особого смысла нет, а если реализация находится в объявлении класса - то это *уже* inline...

Comment: Надо смотреть стандарты. `inline` - это рекомендация компилятору сделать функцию встраиваемой. В 99.999% случаев компилятор сам решает что ему сделать. Не знаю на счёт linux, но на Windows есть `_forceinline` для проталкивания создание встраиваемой функции.

Comment: + это скорее пройдет для эмбедет систем, когда вы точно знаете где и как использовать это интсрукию.

Comment: @MrBin если вы про компилятор Microsoft то он очень часто игнорирует даже _forceinline, даже если вы поставите флаг что необходимо применять _forceinline там где он стоит.

Comment: Надо отключать флаги оптимизации.

Comment: Если что-то не рекомендуется делать, то лучше всего спросить у того, кто это не рекомендует. Если коллега говорит, что не рекомендуется, а обосновать не может, это уже похоже на какой-то культ карго. Я бы на Вашем месте к этому вопросу подошёл с другой стороны: а зачем Вы ставите `inline`? У Вас есть какие-то причины считать, что от этого код станет лучше? Вы измеряли? Доказали, что применение `inline` помогает? Вы уверены, что добавление `inline` не сделает хуже? Рекомендую задать себе эти вопросы и постараться на них ответить.

Comment: @ixSci Я сделал почти так. И кода упёрся в тупик решил посоветоваться с сообществом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основное назначение слова `inline`: дать программисту инструмент определять функции так, чтобы у компилятора **была возможность** встроить их на этапе компиляции и не вызвать в дальнейшем ошибку компоновки.

Вторичное назначение: сообщение другим людям работающим над данным кодом, что автор надеется, что компилятор встроит эту функцию.

Кроме того это действительно является **подсказкой** компилятору встроить функцию (я сам сомневался в этом), которая на самом деле влияет на эвристики компилятора, например, увеличивая пороговые значения размера функции выше которых компилятор откажется её встраивать (смотри ссылку на статью в ответе @ixSci)

Пусть есть класс `Foo` с переменной `a`, к которой нужно обеспечить доступ; есть несколько вариантов, что можно сделать с `getA`:

1. Определить прямо в классе.

   ```
   class Foo {
       int a{0};
   public:
       int Foo::getA () { return a; }
   ```

   `inline` подразумевается, программист сразу понимает что к чему, компоновщик не жалуется о повторном определении. ИМХО — это предпочтительный вариант покуда реализация не занимает больше двух-трёх (пяти?) строк.
2. Определить в хедере вне класса.

   ```
   class Foo {
       int a{0};
   public:
       int getA ();
   }

   int Foo::getA () { return a;}
   ```

   Это тот случай, когда использование слова `inline` обязательно и для чего оно и было введено, но где именно оно будет компилятору всё равно, вопрос **исключительно стилистический**. Распишу плюсы и минусы на мой взгляд (все они **крайне** эфемерны):

   2.1. `inline` только в объявлении — назовём это «основным вариантом».

   2.2. `inline` только в определении — относительно плохой вариант:

   - **-** При просмотре объявления программист будет рассчитывать, что компилятор не сможет (и не должен) встроить функцию, что для геттера вызывает ряд вопрсов и потенциально ложных предположений, например то что этот геттер не тривиальный и требует каких-то вычислений.

   2.3. `inline` и в объявлении и в определении

   - **+** При прочтении и объявления, и определения класса сразу видно, что функция встраиваемая.
   - **-** Чревато скатыванием к предыдущему варианту, если кто-то удалит слово `inline` и не удосужится проверить.
3. Определение в отдельном `*.cpp`.

   ```
   // foo.h
   class Foo {
       int a{0};
   public:
       int getA ();
   }

   // foo.cpp
   #include "foo.h"
   int Foo::getA () { return a;}

   // main.cpp
   #include "foo.h"
   int main(void) {
       Foo foo;
       return foo.getA();
   }
   ```

   Если `inline` будет присутствовать в объявлении или определении, то это нарушение стандарта, который требует, чтобы определение функции объявленной как `inline` было доступно в каждой единице трансляции, где она вызывается и оно было в точности одинаковое.

Comment: Не скорее всего, а совершенно точно ошибка — это прямое нарушение стандарта.

Comment: @ixSci, поправил, спасибо за статью, кстати...

Comment: Сверялся со стандартом и меня сильно смутила фраза из оного: `7.1.2/1 Function-specifiers can be used only in function **declarations**`. Является ли определение «де-юре» также объявлением? или это две разные сущности с точки зрения стандарта?

Comment: Но ведь там явно указаны, что за «specifiers»: virtual, explicit. Что касается второго, то скорее наоборот: декларация является определением за исключением некоторых случаев (всё это описано в [basic.def])

Comment: @ixSci, там virtual, explicit и *inline* до 17-го… но да, в [basic.def] `3.1/2. A declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body…` так что да, с этим всё в порядке… ещё раз спасибо...

Answer (score 3):

У Вас в вопросе не ясно, где у Вас расположена реализация методов `get`/`set`. Если она расположена в том же файле, что и декларация (предположим, что это заголовок), то если Вы пометили декларацию функции как `inline`, то реализацию можно помечать, а можно и не помечать. `inline` у реализации в этом случае будет избыточен. Но тут возникает вопрос, если всё находится в одном файле, то зачем Вам вообще декларация, может сделать только одно определение и этого будет достаточно? Дело вкуса, конечно.

Если же реализация у Вас находится в отдельном файле (скажем, cpp), а заголовок включается не только в него, а ещё в другие файлы, то при использовании функции `get`/`set` в двух разных объектах трансляции (translation unit), Ваша программа становится «сломанной» (ill-formed). Т.е. так делать попросту нельзя, смотрите *[dcl.inline]p6*:

> An inline function or variable **shall be defined in every translation**
>   **unit** in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition
>   in every case

---

> Я знаю, что компиляторы сейчас забивают даже на форсинлайны и обычный
>   inline им вообще не указ.

Не стоит верить всему, что находите в сети, слишком много домыслов и непонятных утверждений можно найти. Посмотрите эту статью: [«Do compilers take inline as a hint?»](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/inline-hints/), там хотя бы конкретные вещи приведены.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Пойду всё это тестировать.